# Is there a filter plugin for Photoshop that allows to turn luminocity to alpha?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask, clipping-mask, filter, plugin

I'm looking for a simple filter that turns luminocity to alpha and works for smart objects. My use case is creating non-destructive workflow luminocity masks and manual HDR photo merge in Photoshop.

Comment: You may want to look into the TK9 Plugin for Photoshop. This allows you to create and easily modify luminosity masks.

Answer (score 3):

No plugin needed:
As Kyle suggested its possible with the 'blend if' tool.

[image]

In layer-style/blend-if drag white arrow with alt to the left.  then put the smart object in a group and create a colour fill with clipping mask to re-colour.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both Lumenzia (by Greg Benz) and Raya Pro (by Jimmy McIntyre) are luminosity masking plug-ins for Photoshop. I have no affiliation with them except that I have purchased and used both. They are quite extensive both in features and in their available teaching/training. There are others available as well. They are for sale and not free.

Another place to look into would be Photoshop's own Blend If functioning which works with blending images by masking out parts of an image based on the luminosity of pixels. It is a simplified luminosity masking feature. There is a lot of available explaining/training available online for free.

Comment: But are they able to achieve what I'm talking about - convert smart object's layer luminosity to transparency (so darker pixels become more transparent pixels and lighter less transparent)?